# Would the version of Chrome affect the behavior of a JavaScript library?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, openlayers, v8, geoserver

I ran into a bug that seems very nuanced and strange. I am using OpenLayers (v4.0.1) in a web application to display multiple WMS layers from a GeoServer (v2.8.2). Everything seemed to be working great until Windows 10 did a big update. Shortly thereafter, my browser began to crash when attempting to view the page on which the map and all of its layers should be displayed.

After a lot of digging, it appeared that this issue only shows up in Chrome Version 60 (60.0.3112.90 to be exact). I tried to reproduce the issue on multiple OS's and browser combinations (Linux/Windows/Mac and Firefox/IE/Edge/Chrome Version 59) and it works great everywhere except on Chrome 60 (across all OS's).

Though still hard to pin-point exactly, when doing a step-through of the JavaScript to find where the hang-up occurs, it is definitely happening somewhere inside of the OpenLayers code. Another key discovery is that the error does not occur at all if the browser window size is "small" enough. In other words, if I resize my window and try again, it will suddenly work consistently once a somewhat-random-seeming, certain browser size is reached. It seems to be more area-dependent, though, than a specific height/width constraint, as various height/width combinations will either work or not work.

At this point I have no great idea on how to resolve this issue, so I'm starting here by simply wondering if anyone knows if it would make sense that something in Chrome 60 is changing the behavior of the OpenLayers JavaScript library? If so, I'd want to open up an official GitHub issue with them. If not, would it be a Chrome issue I'd report? I'm reluctant to believe it is something that I have programmed, as it works in every other browser.

Thoughts?

Comment: It's difficult if not completely impossible to guess at what might be causing this.  Do you have a code sample which exhibits the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This does indeed sound like a Chrome bug. Please file a bug at crbug.com/new, and include:

- repro instructions (ideally, a link to a site that will trigger the crash)
- any crash reports you see in chrome://crashes (if this is what caused them)

If you post the bug number here, I'll make sure it gets looked at. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I just posted the bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=754490